# How to send and receive List using Tcp NetworkStream C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

I just started learning socket programming and now I`m trying to send List<> from Client to Server.

I`ve read that i need to Serialize and Deserialize using BinaryFormatter but i just didnt know how to send it to server using NetworkStream.

Please help and any explanation will be very much appreciated. Thank you very much in advanced.

Below is my code for Client

```
private void btnSendDataToServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int noOfMessage = Convert.ToInt32(tbMessageNo.Text);
        try
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfMessage; i++)
            {
                clientList.Add(tbSendDataToServer.Text);
            }

            //send data to server
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(?); 
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            //receive data from server
            byte[] inStream = new byte[102400]; 
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream); 
            msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);
        }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        { }
    }
```

Below is my code for Server

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[102400];

NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

                    f.testQS.Enqueue(dataFromClient);
                    AppendText(f.testQS.Count().ToString() + " >> " + "From client-" + ClientNo + "--" + dataFromClient);

                    //send data to client
                    rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                    serverResponse = "Server to Client(" + ClientNo + ") " + rCount;
                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
```

P.s. If it is a single string, i have no problem doing it. But i want to loop the string 1st based on the user noOfMessage and put it in List. Then i will send the List to Server. Then, the Server will read List received and display the data of the List. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`, send the byte array returned by the serializer. You're also making the very classical mistake of ignoring the number of bytes returned by `Read()`. You need a message framing protocol. Why are you using sockets like this?

Comment: @CodeCaster I`m doing a lot of things wrong is it? var bin = new BinaryFormatter();
bin.Serialize(serverStream, clientList); Is this correct in using Serialize()? How do i proceed from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send data

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(serverStream, clientList);
serverStream.Close();
```

To Receive at server

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
clientList = (List<string>) formatter.Deserialize(networkStream);
```